# PHP - schedule email send after 24 hours in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom vue frontend to manage user registration in WordPress and a custom plugin that will setup custom rest routes and custom user roles. The workflow is that after the registration an user account will need to be approved from a site moderator. To achive this I have a custom role for moderators and a custom backend also made with vue. After user account approval, I need to delay the sending of credentials to the users and I've discovered that I can use the [cron job of wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/419379/wp-mail-send-emails-after-24-hours-from-users-registration).

I've implemented a similar solution in my plugin code in this way

```php
class myplugin {
  public function __construct()
  {
    add_action('send_user_credential', array($this, 'send_scheduled_registration_email'));
  }
  
  public function send_scheduled_registration_email( $user_email, $subject, $message )
  {
    wp_mail( $user_email, $subject, $message );
  }

  public function create_new_customer( WP_REST_Request $request )
  {
    //other code stuff to save and generate a password
    $user_email = $customer->user_email;
    $num = sanitize_text_field( $request->get_param('num') );
    $subject =  'User approved';
    $message = ".... \n";
    $message .= "...: $num_t \n";
    $message .= "...password: \n";
    $message .= "$password \n";              
    //
    wp_schedule_single_event( DAY_IN_SECONDS * 1, 'send_user_credential', array( $user_email, $subject, $message ));
  }
}
```

At the moment after a 24h hour period I've noticed that emails will be not sended and it's like the scheduled task will be never registered. To try solve the problem I've created a cron in nodejs and using a script I'm calling the wp-cron.php every two hours but not worked. Is there something wrong into the implementation and how I can fix?
The site is at the moment in maintenance mode, but I don't think this can be an issue?